# Посчитать количество повторений каждого уникального значения в столбце базы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица в бд, которая представлена двумя целочисленными столбцами: 
 1. Id пользователя
 2. Id друга пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо написать запрос, который бы посчитал сколько у каждого пользователя друзей. Попробовал следующий запрос, но результат не тот:

```
SELECT `table 9`.`COL 1`, COUNT(`table 9`.`COL 1`) AS friends FROM `table 9` GROUP BY `table 9`.`COL 1`) A'
```

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант, не уверен в нем, ибо времени протестить сейчас нет.

```
SELECT
  `table 9`.`COL 1` as userId,
  (
    SELECT
      count(*)
    FROM
      `table 9`
    WHERE
      `table 9`.`COL 1` = userId
  ) AS friends
FROM
  `table 9`
GROUP BY
  `table 9`.`COL 1`
```

Связи у вас довольно странные, так-то, должна быть таблица юзеры отдельная и в идеале запрос должен быть примерно такой

```
SELECT
  id,
  (
    SELECT
      count(*)
    FROM
      `friends`
    WHERE
      `friends`.`userId` = id
  ) as friendsCount
FROM
  `users`
GROUP BY
  id
```